# How to write raw text verbatim in LyX?

Tags: graphics, lyx, embedding

I want to write PlantUML diagrams from within LyX, and I want to put the result right into the document itself. To do so, I attempted to create a comment environment, in which I put the diagram description.

Basically, PlantUML scans a directory for a bunch of text like the following:

```
@startuml foo.png
(A) --> (B) : x
(B) --> (C) : y
@enduml
```

...converts it on the fly to something GraphViz understands, then writes the output in `foo.png`.

To do this, I tried to put the PlantUML source in a comment block. However, this results in the following output in the LyX file:

```
\begin_inset Note Note
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
@startuml foo.png
\end_layout

<snip/>

\end_inset
```

I tried to work around this by putting the source in an ERT block, but this simply adds a `\begin_inset ERT`, without removing the `\begin_layout` lines. How can I work around this?

Comment: Why not use Tex code blocks?

Comment: @Charles That's what I meant by "ERT" (Evil Red Text), which is supposed to allow raw TeX to be inserted.

Comment: Using Lyx 1.6.8 and pasting in the code above into a Tex code block, I get a Lyx file that contains everything with a lot of unnecessary markup, and which gives the correct Latex output.  Which Lyx are you using?

Comment: Without wanting to be "that guy": why don't you use an alternative TeX editor like TeXworks?

Comment: @Seamus Because with others editors I can't keep up with the lesson while taking notes :)

Comment: @Charles Lyx 2 RC.

Comment: Lyx 2rc1 is marked *Please do not use these for any serious work! They are only provided for testing and development purposes.* - if you don't actually need any of the features of Lyx 2, I recommend "downgrading" to 1.6.9, which I guess will behave as I've seen.

Comment: @Charles I have 1.6.9 on Windows and that version behaves in exactly the same way. Nice try pulling the RTFM card though :)

Comment: A release candidate which you're not supposed to use except for development purposes? Now that's a novel idea… :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the same problem, but to document fully what I see: your Plant UML lines when placed in a Tex code block in my Lyx 1.6.8 are represented in the .lyx file so:

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@startuml foo.png 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

(A) --> (B) : x 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

(B) --> (C) : y 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@enduml
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout
```

Using Lyx's export to Latex gives the original three lines back in the exported .tex file.

I count this as "works for me" - do you see or want a different behaviour?

Comment: That's what I see, and that's bad, because I don't want to export to Latex to update the images :)

Comment: @badp: Now I understand the problem.  You could put Latex code to create an external file using `filecontents` and run Plant UML on that.  Do you want some example code, or is that clear?

Comment: +1 because I don't think an earnest and competent attempt at help should ever result in -1.